# how to resolve /src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve './serviceWorker' in 'C:\Users\hp\weather\src'

Tags: reactjs

I was building a weather app in react and I got the following error

> /src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve './serviceWorker' in 'C:\Users\hp\weather\src'

what to do now?

Comment: Can you provide the code inside index.js and also the image of all the files inside the src/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have deleted the `serviceWorker.js` file from the `src/` folder.

If it is not required, remove the `import` statement from the index.js file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've used '**npm cache clean**' command
it asked me use same command along with --force.
so, I used this '**npm cache clean --force**'.
my issue got resolved.